# Artifactory plugin for rundeck?

Tags: tomcat, artifactory, rundeck

I have been unable to find a plugin to list available artifacts from Artifactory.

Does anyone know of a method to do this in a rundeck job, I want to deploy a war file which is available In artifactory to tomcat using rundeck.

Regarding deployments to tomcat in rundeck what are best practices there ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Job option with [remote option values](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#remote-option-values), which will fetch the list of artifacts from Artifactory.
Since Rundeck support limited [JSON format](http://rundeck.org/docs/manual/jobs.html#json-format), you will not be able to use most of the Artifactory REST APIs directly. What you can do instead is develop an Artifactory user plugin of type [Excutions](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Executions).
User plugins allows you to easily extend Artifactory's behavior with your own code written in Groovy. The plugins can use the [Artifactory public API](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/index.html), which contains everything you will need for getting a list of artifacts.
You can develop a plugin which contains your own logic for searching artifacts and can control the format of the JSON response. Executions user plugins are executed using REST calls and therefor can be called from Rundeck.
Please notice that user plugins required the Pro version of Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Artifactory REST API, namely [Artifact Version Search](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactVersionSearch).