# Pull certain artifacts from Artifactory(JFrog) into my Rundeck Server

Tags: jenkins, devops, rundeck

I would like to pull certain artifacts from Artifactory(JFrog) into my Rundeck Server so as to deploy them on remote nodes.

Is there any Artifactory plugin that I can add to Rundeck..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Artifactory API REST on some python/bash script step, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25157800). [Here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API) the full reference.